# Remove apostrophe from string Python regex

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
i've been running from what i don't know if she's there or if she's cares it's taken you a long time to see you've got a goldfish memory this song's ed'
```

How do I use a regex to remove all apostrophe that is between words? I tried using `re.sub('(?<=[a-z])'(?=[a-z])', '', s)` but cannot get the desired result.

Comment: do you need to use regex? why won't replace work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to escape the single quote in your regex to distinguish it from the pattern which is also in single quotes:

```
re.sub('(?<=[a-z])\'(?=[a-z])', '', s)
```

But, another solution would be to just use double quotes for the entire pattern:

```
re.sub("(?<=[a-z])'(?=[a-z])", "", s)
```

Comment: Isn't `re.sub('([a-z]+)\'([a-z]+)', '\\1', s)` better?

Comment: @MehdiAbbassi Actually, perhaps not, as invoking a capture group might have some additional overhead versus the answer I posted above using lookarounds.  You could try to benchmark both versions and see what you find.

Answer (score 4):

If it's not set in stone that you have to use regex;

```
sentence = r"i've been running from what i don't know if she's there or if she's cares it's taken you a long time to see you've got a goldfish memory this song's ed'"

print(sentence.replace("'", ""))
```

OUTPUT:

```
>>> ive been running from what i dont know if shes there or if shes cares its taken you a long time to see youve got a goldfish memory this songs ed
```

Regarding Kevin's comment, using the `count` of the occurrences less 1;

```
print(sentence.replace("'", "", sentence.count("'")-1))
```

OUTPUT:

```
>>> ive been running from what i dont know if shes there or if shes cares its taken you a long time to see youve got a goldfish memory this songs ed'
```

Comment: My interpretation of the requirements is that the final apostrophe after the final word, "ed," should not be removed.

Comment: Added an alternative suggestion taking that into account.

Comment: But what if the string is `"the abc's songs' lyrics can't be too hard"`? Then it'll become `"the abcs songs lyrics can't be too hard"`.